# How to fix "your computer is running in low graphics mode"

Tags: graphics

I can get to the terminal from the screen that says "your computer is running in low graphics mode" but cant get to my desktop or anything. Please help!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/141606/44179